# RegExp exec - string manipulation

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string that I am trying to manipulate using a regular expression as follows:

```
var str = 'This is a string with 1: {{param1}}, 2: {{param2}} and 3: {{param3}}',
    reg = /{{.*?}}/ig;

while (field = reg.exec(str)) {
    str = str.replace(field, 'test');
}
```

`{{param2}}` never gets replaced though - my guess is because I am manipulating the string while running it through `RegExp.exec(...)`. But cannot be certain.

I have tried the following (as I noticed `RegExp.exec(...)` returns an array) - still no luck:

```
var str = 'This is a string with 1: {{param1}}, 2: {{param2}} and 3: {{param3}}',
    reg = /{{.*?}}/ig;

while (field = reg.exec(str)) {
    str = str.replace(field[0], 'test');
}
```

Any ideas?

**Edit:** current result of this function is:

```
'This is a string with 1: test, 2: {{param2}}, test and 3: test'
```

Comment: You need to escape those curly braces in your regex pattern.

Comment: Thanks - didn't work still I'm afraid

Comment: Also, the `i` is meaningless here.

Answer (score 3):

You should remove the `g` flag.

```
var str = 'This is a string with 1: {{param1}}, 2: {{param2}} and 3: {{param3}}',
    reg = /{{.*?}}/; 



while (field = reg.exec(str)) {
    str = str.replace(field, 'test');
    console.log(str)
}
```

Result :

First iteration :

> This is a string with 1: test, 2: {{param2}} and 3: {{param3}}

Second :

> This is a string with 1: test, 2: test and 3: {{param3}}

third :

> This is a string with 1: test, 2: test and 3: test

Another option is to do :

```
 str = str.replace(/{{.*?}}/g, 'test');
```

This will also yield :

> This is a string with 1: test, 2: test and 3: test

**Edit :**

To add  to Anonymous's answer :

The problem is that each `replace` - makes the original string shorter.The indexes were calculated at the *beginning* with the original longer line .

In other words , had you wanted to replace to a same length expression as `{{param1}}` (which it's length is 9) , to another string with same length of 9 , say : `**test1**` , then your code would have worked :

```
var str = 'This is a string with 1: {{param1}}, 2: {{param2}} and 3: {{param3}}',
    reg = /{{.*?}}/g


while (field = reg.exec(str)) {

    str = str.replace(field, '**test1**');
    console.log(str)
}
```

Result :

> `This is a string with 1: **test1**, 2: **test1** and 3: **test1**`

Comment: Nice! Thanks so much. I don't suppose you can explain why it doesn't work with the global flag?

Comment: Or you can keep the `g` flag and ditch the `while` loop (keep the replace, though, swapping in `reg` for `field`).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) by supplying a function:

```
var text = 'This is a string with 1: {{param1}}, 2: {{param2}} and 3: {{param3}}';

var result = text.replace(/{{.*?}}/g, function (match) {
    // *match* contains the full match, if you have captures
    // then they will be handed in as additional arguments 
    return 'test';
});
```

To my eyes this is much cleaner than messing with the indices and such. [See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/akf18r3x/1/) for a working version.

Comment: I wasn't aware `replace` can use a callback for the 2nd parameter - that's awesome, thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help, this doesn't seem to be widely known for some reason. I learned about it from [John Resig's "Secret of the JavaScript Ninja"](http://ejohn.org/blog/secrets-of-the-javascript-ninja-released/), it's a good read - although he's got a samurai on the cover, not a ninja :-)

Comment: Ha - I know the book but I've not read it in great detail! After your answer here, I will do now :). Considering he created one of the most well known JS libraries in existence!

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. It just barely misses due to the replacement. The following is the execution order of the regular expression matching:

- After the first exec, `reg.lastIndex` is set to 35.
- The remaining string to check then becomes `', 2: {{param2}} and 3: {{param3}}'`
- After the first replacement, the remaining string to match becomes `'{param2}} and 3: {{param3}}'` since the `lastIndex` doesn't change from 35.
- The next iteration of regular expression matching occurs, but it doesn't match `{param2}}`, so it keeps matching until reaching `'{{param3}}'`.

This all occurs because the `g`lobal regex flag saves the `lastIndex`. Instead, you can remove the global flag to automatically have the `lastIndex` set to `0` after termination of a single match. However, this does mean that the regular expression will always start matching from the beginning. The better option is to set the `lastIndex` to a position where you need it.

```js
var str = 'This is a string with 1: {{param1}}, 2: {{param2}} and 3: {{param3}}',
    reg = /{{.*?}}/ig,
    replacement = 'test';

while (field = reg.exec(str)) {
    str = str.replace(field[0], replacement);
    reg.lastIndex = reg.lastIndex - field[0].length + replacement.length;
}
console.log(str);
```

Comment: Wasn't aware there was a `lastIndex` property - most helpful for debugging! Thanks.

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help.